# GetPrivateProfileString returning no values :VB.net

Tags: vb.net, kernel32

I am new to VB and is working on VB6 to VB.net migration.
One of the solution is migrated successfully and am working on the second one.

```
Dim temp As New System.Text.StringBuilder(1024)
Public Sub Main()
    Dim i As Integer = GetPrivateProfileString("WinFlex", "UserPath", "", temp, 1024, "C:\WINDOWS\Win.Ini")
End Sub
<DllImport("kernel32")> _
Private Function GetPrivateProfileString(ByVal section As String, ByVal key As String, ByVal def As String, ByVal retVal As System.Text.StringBuilder, ByVal size As Integer, ByVal filePath As String) As Integer
End Function
```

This particular code needs (temp) to return a working directory for my Ini file (something like "C:\WinFlex6\1"), but instead it is returning me a blank value. 
The same code works on a different solution (someone else migrated it).
I am not sure what the issue is, I tried several fixes present on the web but none worked.

Can anyone help me out on this one?

Earlier it was working fine, but after some debugging it stopped working.

Comment: Do you have an option to move away from ini files entirely - as noted in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), "This function is provided only for compatibility with **16-bit Windows**-based applications. Applications should store initialization information in the registry", ie it's _really_ legacy by now.

Comment: No actually, we still need this. Since once of the application is successfully migrated my client wants to stick with this.

Comment: Not sure if this will solve your problem, but try with `<DllImport("kernel32")> Public Shared Function GetPrivateProfileString .....` (of course you are sure that there is a section named WinFlex with a key named UserPath  right?)

Comment: Where is the allocation of a buffer (`temp`) to receive the information? Where is the test of the return value (`i`) to see if it worked or not? Where are you trying to access the value after the call? Does the entry actually exist in `C:\Windows\Win.ini` on the system where the app is running? The code specifically says to return a blank (`""`) if the entry isn't found. It didn't "work, but after some debugging stop".

Comment: Steve -Yes, there is a section named WinFlex with a key named UserPath .
KenWhite - I have added the buffer and yes the entry does exist on the system application is running.

Comment: Also check if you have this situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891279/why-cant-i-get-getprivateprofilestring-to-work-via-pinvoke

Comment: Your suggestion worked Steve!   Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys, I am naïve in vb therefore was doing this silly mistake.
Thanks [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1197518/steve%20Steve)
for bringing this up.

The issue was, I was/am declaring the function in a module.

```
<DllImport("kernel32")> _
Private Function GetPrivateProfileString(ByVal section As String, ByVal key As String, ByVal def As String, ByVal retVal As System.Text.StringBuilder, ByVal size As Integer, ByVal filePath As String) As Integer
End Function
```

This function can be "Shared Function" which can be added in a class.

```
Public Shared Function
```

Once I declared it as inside a vb class

```
<DllImport("kernel32")> _
Public Shared Function GetPrivateProfileString(ByVal section As String, ByVal key As String, ByVal def As String, ByVal retVal As System.Text.StringBuilder, ByVal size As Integer, ByVal filePath As String) As Integer
End Function
```

Bingo! It worked!
Thanks to [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1197518/steve%20Steve)
again!!

Comment: Glad you have found the bug.

Comment: Hey Steve, there is new bug I found, whenever I open the solution for the first time, it again stops working. But if I exclude and include my class file it starts working,. Do you have any idea what wrong in this?